# React-native pass Json values to react native <input

Tags: json, react-native

### **Hello friends,**

I am just starting with react-native to create one app for android cel.
I have a form with 2 fields  / and I want to load those fields from json that I pull from php file.
If I send only one value through json I can load that value in one field using "componentDidMount" and "XMLHttpRequest()"
This is the code I am using at componentdidmount:

```
componentDidMount=()=> {
  let _this= this;
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      console.log(this.responseText);
      var temp = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      console.log(temp);
      _this.setState({datos: temp});
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', 'https://smppage.000webhostapp.com/gest_ObtFolio2.php', true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

These are the values printed in the console.log:
responsetext:
LOG  [{"iddeOS":"13"},{"fecha":"2021-12-04"}]
temp:
LOG  [{"iddeOS": "13"}, {"fecha": "2021-12-04"}]

When I only send one field through json I can load it in one field but I want to send 2 fields over json, this is the value that I send over json for only one field:
responsetext:
LOG  "14"
temp:
LOG  14
This is the code that I use in one  /  when I pull only one field and and that field is correctly loaded at my

```
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Input
                ref={component => this.folioOrden = component}
                label=" Folio"
                value={this.state.datos.toString()}
```

With this code it correctly loads the value in one field

can you help to find the code to fill the 2 fields "Folio" and "Fecha"at the same time with component did mount?

```
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Input
                ref={component => this.folioOrden = component}
                label=" Folio"
                value={this.state.datos.toString()}
            <View style={{flex:2}}>
              <Input
                ref={component => this.fechaAperOrden = component}
                label=" Fecha"
```

I already tried sendinf the 2 fields and using this code in both inputs but I shows errors:

```
value={this.state.datos.iddeOS.toString()}
value={this.state.datos.fecha.toString()}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use destructuring with your response:

```
this.setState({...temp});
```

If the content of **temp** is:

```
{iddeOS:'SomeValue',fecha:'2021-12-04'}
```

it will replace the state to:

```
this.state.iddeOS
this.state.fecha
```